# Heroku error: we're sorry something went wrong, check application logs - syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, syntax, erb

When deploying my rails app to heroku i get the following error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

I checked the logs with:

```
 heroku logs
```

It shows a lot of syntax errors:

```
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266169+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/users/index.html.erb:50: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266171+00:00 app[web.1]: ...'data-target': "#modal-window"} do@output_buffer.safe_append...
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266173+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266175+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/users/index.html.erb:53: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266218+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/users/index.html.erb:55: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266220+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                 'data-toggle':"modal", 'data-target': "#mod...
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266221+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266223+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/users/index.html.erb:55: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266225+00:00 app[web.1]: ...         'data-toggle':"modal", 'data-target': "#modal-windo...
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266226+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266228+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/users/index.html.erb:55: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
2015-08-11T20:11:57.266229+00:00 app[web.1]: ...toggle':"modal", 'data-target': "#modal-window", class: "sta...
```

However, in my development mode, I have no syntax errors and everything works fine.

Here is the part of the code giving the syntax error:

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="allposts">
                <%current_user.friends.each do |x|%>
                  <%x.posts.order(created_at: :desc).each do |y|%>
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <%=y.created_at.strftime("%b %d %Y")%>
                        <span id="time">
                          <%=y.created_at.strftime("%l:%M%P")%>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <%=link_to user_profile_path(x) do%>
                            <%=image_tag(x.profile_picture.url, class: 'feedprofilepic')%><br>
                            <span>
                              <%=y.user.email%>
                            </span>
                            <%end%>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9">
                            <%if y.type=="Image"%> ***(LINE 50 HERE)***

                              <!-- link_to can accept block, this will make whole picture containing div a link -->
                              <%=link_to post_path(y), {remote:true, 'data-toggle': "modal", 'data-target': "#modal-window"} do%>
                                  <%=image_tag(y.body.url, :style=>'max-width:100%;max-height:100%;')%>
                              <%end%><br>
                            <%else%>
                              <%=link_to post_path(y), {remote:true,
                              'data-toggle':"modal", 'data-target': "#modal-window", class: "statuslink"} do%>
                                <h2>
                                  <div class="status">
                                    <%=y.body%>
                                  </div>
                                </h2>
                              <%end%>
                            <%end%>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

In Chrome, dev tools i get a 500 error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Note: I have installed the rails 12 factor gem in the production env, i still get this error. This code works as is in development mode with no syntax errors. Any ideas/help please?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have a syntax error in your hash:

```
{remote:true, 'data-toggle':"modal", 'data-target': "#modal-window", class: "statuslink"}
```

In particular, you cannot define symbol hash keys with an appended `:` when those keys contain a hyphen. (This should be true regardless of environment since its a Ruby syntax issue, so your comment that it works in development is odd.) Instead, you have to define those hash key-value pairs using the old `=>`:

```
{remote:true, class: "statuslink", :'data-toggle' => "modal", :'data-target' => "#modal-window"}
```

Note that Rails also supports defining `data-*` attributes with a nested hash:

```
{remote:true, class: "statuslink", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#modal-window"}}
```

This does not work for arbitrary hyphenated attributes, however.

Comment: thanks, that fixed the problem , but  it works without these changes in development mode, can anyone explain why ?

Comment: Are you sure? Its not valid Ruby. Perhaps you were loading different code? Make sure nothing is cached...